Closed form expression for A099398
I am trying to derive a closed form expression for A099398, I came up with the following
$$\frac{\lambda  (2 n)!}{n! (n+1)! (k n-1) \left(2^n-\sum _{p=0}^{n+1} \left\lfloor \frac{(n+1)!}{2 p! (n-p+1)!}\right\rfloor \right)}$$
where $\lambda = 1$, $k = 2$. It is very close, except that at "certain" positions, there are divisions by 3 ($\{1,\frac{1}{3},1,1,\frac{7}{3},3,33,\frac{143}{3},143,221,\frac{4199}{3},2261,7429,\frac{37145}{3},334305\}$). These positions seem to be described by A356447.
Is there an adjustment to the above expression to address this issue?
If you are interested, here is the corresponding Mathematica function:
A099398D[n_, k_, \[Lambda]_] := (\[Lambda]*(2 n)!)/(
n! (n + 1)! (k n - 1) (2^n - 
   Sum[Floor[(n + 1)!/(2 p! (n + 1 - p)!)], {p, 0, n + 1}]))

Table[A099398D[n, 2, 1], {n, 1, 400}]

Note: I have not proved that it is correct except for confirming the (near-)equivalence (because of the issue mentioned above) of the sequences for substantially large $n$.

What is the actual question? If anyone can help you to fix your formula? Whether it is close to being correct at all? ...?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@JulesLamers I added some details and clarified the question statement.
